# Netsuite RESTlet - nlapiSubmitRecord() return null when create sales order containing assembly items

Tags: netsuite

When I send rest call to Netsuite and create a new sales order via RESTlet, I found that my code could work perfectly if the sales order 'item' field only contains inventoryitems. However, when the sales order contains assemblyitem or kit/package item, the nlapiSubmitRecord() function will return null and no sales order will be created. (No error is thrown as well)
Could anyone please tell me the reason? Thanks!

My RESTlet function to create a new sales order is as follows:

```
function createSalesorder(datain) {
    // init message and sales order obj
    var message = new Object();
    var record = nlapiCreateRecord('salesorder'); 
    // check if the sales order already exists in Netsuite
    if(!datain['otherrefnum']){
        message.status = 'failed',
        message.message = 'missing Customer P.O.';
        return message;
    } else {
        var filters = new Array();
        var columns = new Array();
        filters.push(new nlobjSearchFilter('otherrefnum', null, 'equalto', datain['otherrefnum']));
        filters.push(new nlobjSearchFilter('entity', null, 'is', datain['entity']));
        // columns.push(new nlobjSearchColumn('otherrefnum', null, null));
        var search = nlapiSearchRecord(datain.recordtype, null, filters, columns);
        if(search && search.length>0){
            message.status = 'duplicated',
            message.id = search[0].id;
            return message;
        }
    }
    // check input data has required fields
    if(!datain['item']){
        message.status = 'failed';
        message.message = 'missing item';
        return message;
    }
    if(!datain['entity']){
        message.status = 'failed';
        message.message = 'missing customer id';
        return message;
    }
    // init fields with default values
    if(!datain['custbody_shipping_reason']){
        record.setFieldValue('custbody_shipping_reason',1);
    }
    if(!datain['custbody_order_type']){
        record.setFieldValue('custbody_order_type',1);
    }
    if(!datain['shipmethod']){
        record.setFieldValue('shipmethod', 4304);
    }
    if(!datain['location']){
        record.setFieldValue('location', 21);
    }
    if(!datain['istaxable']){
        record.setFieldValue('taxitem', -8);
    }
    // load data input
    for(var fieldname in datain){
        switch(fieldname){
            case 'recordtype':
            case 'type':
            case 'id':
                break;
            case 'istaxable':
                record.setFieldValue(fieldname, datain[fieldname]);
                if(datain[fieldname] == 'T') record.setFieldValue('taxitem', 2908);
                else record.setFieldValue('taxitem', -8);
            case 'item':
                for(var i = 0; i < datain[fieldname].length; i++){
                    for(var itemfield in datain[fieldname][i]){
                        record.setLineItemValue('item', itemfield, i+1, datain[fieldname][i][itemfield]);
                    }
                }
                break;
            default:
                record.setFieldValue(fieldname, datain[fieldname]);
                break;
        }
    }
    // submit record
    var recordID = nlapiSubmitRecord(record, true);
    nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'Create a new salesorder, id = '+recordID);
    // return results
    message.status = 'create';
    message.id = recordID;
    var order_entity = nlapiLoadRecord('salesorder', message.id);
    message.refid = order_entity.getFieldValue('tranid');
    return message;
}
```

Update 1: I tried to run the same code in Netsuite debugger, it turns out to successfully write the sales order, besides that is came up with a warning:

```
warning Items on this line have been drop shipped or special ordered. Are you sure you want to modify it?
```

Not sure if this is the issue that prevents me to save the sales order properly in production mode.

Comment: Have you tried simulating your code by manually doing the same operations in the GUI? It's possible your assembly items have some restriction on them, like a different department or subsidiary. Also, have you tried debugging the RESTlet with the debugger? You may also try running snippets of the code from within the console in Chrome or firefox, as another method to debug.

Comment: @TonyH Thank you for your suggestion. I've tried manually create a sales order with assembly item, and it seems exactly the same to me as the way I manually created sales orders with inventory item. However I do realize that for assembly item the system will automatically create a work order to be built while for inventory item no such thing is needed. I was wondering if that is the difference but not so sure how to build a work order via RESTlet. I'll try debugging the code with Netsuite debugger. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I think that's because assemblyitem or kit/package item has different required fields so you should add values to them manually.

Please try and let me know the issues.

Comment: Hi Grant, thanks for your suggestion! May I ask if you have any idea how could I check what field is required for assemblyitem or kit/package item? The process to manually add an inventoryitem and an assemblyitem in a sales order looks the same to me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Finally I resolved this issue ... It comes from role permission. I realized that the role that I used to conduct REST call is a customized role, not administrator. To create sales order with assembly or kit/package item, the role needs to have permission to create work order. So the solution is to add permission to your role to create work order, just as below:

[image]

It locates in Setup - Users/Roles - Manage Roles - [Your Role Name] - Permissions - Transactions.

If you are using the administrator role for REST call, this won't bother since you already have (in my understanding) full access to all resources.

Thanks again for all your help and comments! Also hope this could help anyone having the same issue!